# How to do LOOP record by KEY FIELD DATE in RPGLE?

Tags: loops, rpgle

I'm stuck to get the full output.

Supposedly the output need to look like this :
[image: Actual output]

And this is my physical file:
[image: CUREXG]

I have three field in physical file which are :

- EXGDAT = date
- EXGCOD = exchange code
- EXGRAT = exchange rate

My output look like this :

[image: Output]

My output displayed record for 1 June only and not both 31 May and 1 June. What should I do to get the exact output that I want? Please help me. Thanks in advance

Comment: I would try a SETGT and then READ without key after the write to the subfile.  But why not try using SQL?   Within the SQL select, use an SQL function to get the exchange rate of each specific currency, Once you get the hang of it your code will be more readable.

Comment: Actually i want to avoid using sql since i'm not learn that part yet. do you have any suggestion? I would like to use reade instead

Comment: Is it my loop are correct?

Comment: it is not rocket science. ;)  You can learn two methods at the same time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the inner loop runs until `%eof`.  Then you write to the subfile.  The `reade` that follows the write to the subfile will return %eof because the cursor into the file has not been reset.

```
            write sfl01
    exgdat  reade curexg
```

use `SETGT` and then `READ` to read to the `EXGDAT` of the next set of currency rate records.

```
            write sfl01
    exgdat  setgt curexg
            read  curexg
```

to debug the problem where you are not reading the records you expect, try to write the results of every read to a print file. That way you have something you can look at after the program runs. Might help understand what was read and why.

```
FQSYSPRT   o    f  132        printer OflInd(*inOf)    

d lineData        s            132a     

      if          *inof = '1' ;                          
      except      newPage ;                              
      endif ;                                            
      lineData    = %eof + ' ' + exgcod + ' ' + 
                    %editc(exgrat:'J') +
                    ' ' + %char(exgdat:*iso) ;      
      except      detail ;                               

OQsysprt   E            NewPage           1            
O                       LineData           132         
                                                       
O          E            Detail      1                  
O                       LineData           132
```

Comment: I see, okay, so for now, I already try as you suggested, and the date are both displayed, but now, my value is the problem. I mean that, the value for GBP,EUR,AUD,SGD are not displayed. Only USD has been displayed on the screen

Comment: When i debug, i realize that when it goes to select exgcod function, it only move USD value and read the next date then move another USD value for that date, and straightaway to end of the loop. I'm so sorry for asking a lot of questions since i'm a newbie in this language, thanks in advance

Comment: what are the key fields of the curexg input file?   USD being the last of the exchange codes might be a clue.  And, remember to clear the subfile fields after writing the subfile record. Otherwise, the next write to the subfile could show the values of the prior write.

Comment: My key field for curexg is EXGDAT

Comment: files should always have unique keys.  In this case, the keys should be EXGDAT, EXGCOD. But for debugging this problem, probably does not matter.

Comment: But before that,  the write sfl01 must be in the loop or outside of the loop?

Comment: Thank you sir! I finally made it. Thank you so much for your help !